# how to wait for promise resolve rxjs filter

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In my `observable` source I receive events in which I want to filter for a certain async operation.

For instance:

```
s$.pipe(
    map((x) => x + 1),
    filter((x) => alreadyExist(x)))
  .subscribe(...)
```

When `alreadyExist` is an async operation,
(checking if the value exist in a persistent storage) which returns a boolean.

Assume `alreadyExist` return a promise which resolve to a boolean,
how can I `wait` on the return?
Note that I need the value not to change.
Doing `async-await` didn't work and the subscribe executed before the filter returned.

Comment: Can't right now, I will let you know later, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with my suggestion - Using `switchMap` pipe

```
let isAlreadyExist = false; // "global" variable :)
s$.pipe(
    map((x) => x + 1),
    switchMap(async (x) => {
      isAlreadyExist = await alreadyExist(x); // make sure alreadyExist is a promise func
      return x; // "do" do nothing with your data
    }),
    filter((x) => isAlreadyExist)) // isAlreadyExist is value of alreadyExist func
  .subscribe(...)
```

or you can read about `defer` of `RxJS Observable`.

Answer (score 9):

If `alreadyExist` returns a `boolean` you can use `mergeMap` that will wait for its result and if it's `true` than it'll map it into the original `x` value. When it's `false` then it's just filtered out by `filter`.

```
s$.pipe(
    map((x) => x + 1),
    mergeMap(x => from(alreadyExist(x)).pipe(
      filter(Boolean),
      mapTo(x),
    )),
  )
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: how did you `pipe` the promise?

Comment: If `alreadyExist` returns a Promise you'll have to wrap it with `from`